# Javascript regex to convert ruby hash syntax from 1.8 to 1.9

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, angularjs

Greetings I am trying to convert Ruby hashes from the old 1.8 style using AngularJS with a regex

`{ :name => "james" }`

to the newer 1.9 syntax

`{ name: 'james' }`

I am attempting to do this in Angular JS

with the following segment

```
 $scope.$watch("rubyText", function( newValue ) {
   var newVal= newValue.replace(
      new RegExp( "([\w\d_]+)(\s*)=>/\1:", "g" ),
      newValue
   );
   $scope.rubyTextConverted = newVal;   
 }
```

I have limited JS regex experience and would like some advice on the regular expression

Thanks

Comment: What's really going on here? Do you have some `some_ruby_hash.inspect` output in a JavaScript string that you need to convert to a JavaScript data structure?

Comment: I am often converting old syntax to new syntax, and would like to make a quick tool to convert it that I can host on the internet to use

Comment: So I want to be able to copy my hash (from my code or wherever) and paste it into a website that will convert the syntax

Comment: Heres a link that may help. https://coderwall.com/p/8zmazq

Answer (score 0):

You *may* have to account for some edge cases like formatting, whitespace and such (unless it's scrubbed through ruby first). But to get you started here is a very basic version. You would have to add in support for Arrays and numbers and underscores. `{ key: [] }`

```
var regex = /:(\w*)\s?(=>)\s?("\w*")/gi;
var string = '{ :name => "james", :lastname => "rogers" }';

string.replace(regex, "$1: $3");
 //=> '{ name: "james", lastname: "rogers" }'
```

Read up on back references in regex: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#grouping-back-references

Comment: Thanks `{ :a => "b", :b => [ :test => true ], :c => 12 }` is what I am trying to get working

Comment: This is what I have - but not working 100%
`var regex = /([^\:])\:([a-zA-Z_0-9]+[\?\!]?)(\s*)=\>(\s*)/;`